# How to call formhandlers and Droplets without DSP Tags in ATG

Tags: forms, jsp, atg, atg-dynamo

I would like to know about how can we call handle methods of Form Handlers and Droplets from the JSP in ATG without using DSP Tags. Also, suppose in case we want to retrieve the value of a bean in the JSP without using dsp:getvalueof tags , how can we do that ...

Comment: One way would be to not use ATG. What are you trying to achieve by not using `DSP` tags?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ATG REST Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24152_01/Platform.10-1/ATGWSFrameGuide/html/s1201partiiiatgplatformrestwebservice01.html); it permits the calling of Formhandlers without dsp tags.

Answer (score 0):

DSP tags specially used for ATG nucleus components and playing with dynamic data on JSP pages.
I would say, there is no way to use ATG components without DSP tags.

Following is link you can refer to use DSP tags [DSP Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/PageDevGuide/html/s1201appendixadsptaglibraries01.html)

Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use them?
In-fact due to DSP tags, accessing ATG components dynamically on JSP page has become easier.